# MS Access form Validations from VB scriptproblem: complete logic executing when initial if logic validation not satisfied also

Tags: ms-access

I have input from Form Name,Branch (text) x,y and Total are (number) fields

- Record needs to be saved when user provides all the input fields
- Total field = sum (x + Y)

I tried the below code during testing ...

Problem:

I provided the name field data but Branch was provided null and tried to save.. ( Below logic sending message "A value is required for Branch ..."
 when clicked on ok still logic is validating the validatenum function and sending message if total is not equal...

But I need form to stop when first validation failed itself it show branch data missing message and control should go to branch filed and other logic should not get executed..

I think I am doing something wrong with the logic .. can some help me with this simple logic...

I also given outline VB logic here.

---

Code:

```
---------
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit
Dim cancel As Boolean
---------------------------
Public sub save_click()
call validateinput
call validatenum
DoCmd.RunCommand acSaveRecord
End sub 
----------------------------
Private Sub validatenum()

If Me.Total.Value = Me.X.Value + Me.Y.Value then 

Else
MsgBox " Total s not matched with x + Y feilds"", vbRetryCancel
End If
End sub
----------------------------
Private Sub validateinput()
If Me.Name.ListIndex = -1 Then
  MsgBox "A value is required for Namefeild ..."
  Me.Name.SetFocus
    cancel = True

End If

If Me.Branch.ListIndex = -1 Then
  MsgBox "A value is required for Branch ..."
  Me.Branch.SetFocus
    cancel = True

End If
End sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add line with text "Exit Sub" before "End If" for each validation

PS: Read your code once again and noticed that "cancel = True" actually does nothing, so I would rewrite it something like this:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit
---------------------------
Public sub save_click()
    Dim ValidateResult As String
    ValidateResult = Validate()
    If ValidateResult = "" 
        DoCmd.RunCommand acSaveRecord
    Else
        MsgBox ValidateResult
    End If
End sub 
----------------------------
Private Function Validate() As String
    Validate = ""
    If Me.Name.ListIndex = -1 Then
        Validate = "A value is required for Namefeild ..."
        Me.Name.SetFocus
    ElseIf Me.Branch.ListIndex = -1 Then
        Validate = "A value is required for Branch ..."
        Me.Branch.SetFocus
    ElseIf Me.Total.Value <> Me.X.Value + Me.Y.Value then 
        Validate = "Total s not matched with x + Y feilds"
    End If
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

You would be better to bring both types of validation into one function rather than the two, a function will also allow you to return a value whereas sub's do not, this should be cleaner:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Public Sub Save_Click()

    If Not ValidateForm Then
        Exit Sub
    Else
        DoCmd.RunCommand acSaveRecord
    End If

End Sub

Public Function ValidateForm() As Boolean

    ValidateForm = False

    If Me.Total.Value <> Me.X.Value + Me.Y.Value Then
        MsgBox "Total's not matched with x + y fields"
        Exit Function
    End If

    If Me.Name.ListIndex = -1 Then
        MsgBox "A value is required for Namefield"
        Me.Name.SetFocus
        Exit Function
    End If

    If Me.Branch.ListIndex = -1 Then
        MsgBox "A value is required for Branch"
        Me.Branch.SetFocus
        Exit Function
    End If

    ValidateForm = True

Exit Function
```

This basically sets the validation to False immediately and will only change to true if it can pass through all three If statements.  Then on the save click we simply check whether the function returns true or false : )

Comment: Can some one help me with this find Edit record login in VB ms access form..

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8867072/ms-access-form-to-edit-specific-record-from-a-form-by-providing-input-through-te