# MS Access form to edit specific record from a form by providing input through text box

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

Can someone please help me on this find specific record Edit through MS access Forms

I have **Frmfind** form where I have one filed "ticket#" is a input text box
another filed was button "find"

When I enter ticket# which is primary key for my table. I need get the the specific ticket# record should be opened in FormEdit mode using VBA code...

So I have another form "frmEdit" of specific record which has to be called from frmfind -> specific input..

note: Ticket# is column in my table whcih it is primary to have the  ticket#.

Code:

```
Option Compare Database

Private Sub find_Click()

If IsNull(Me.Text79) Or Me.Text79 = "" Then
            MsgBox "You must enter a Ticket #", vbOKOnly, "Required Data"
            Me.Text79.SetFocus
        Exit Sub
    End If

If [Ticket#] = Me.Text79.Value Then


MsgBox "Record found"

DoCmd.Close
DoCmd.OpenForm "frmEdit"

Else


MsgBox "not matching record"
Me.Text79.SetFocus

End If

End Sub

Private Sub Form_Open(cancel As Integer)
'On open set focus to text box
Me.Text79.SetFocus
End Sub
```

Comment: If you are not familiar with VBA, it may be easier to put a combobox on frmEdit using the wizard, it will allow you to select "find a record on my form", so the user only has to choose a ticket number for the record to appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code:

```
Private Sub Command112_Click()

   Me.txtSeach.SetFocus
   On Error Resume Next
   DoCmd.OpenForm "frmEdit", , , "TicketNumber = '" & Nz(Me.text79, "") & "'"

End Sub
```

Note in above if TicketNumber is in fact a number column and not text, then remove the single quotes and use this:

```
   DoCmd.OpenForm "aa", , , "TicketNumber = " & Nz(Me.text79, "")
```

Then for your message, just place that code in the forms on-open event that has a cancel:

eg:

```
Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)

   If IsNull(Me!TicketNumberID) Then
      MsgBox "Please enter a valid Ticket #", vbOKOnly, "Required Data"
      Cancel = True
   End If

End Sub
```

The above assumes your search column is ticket number. 
You can also use dlookup(), or even dcount(). I think above is less code, but:

```
Dim strWhere         As String

strWhere = "TicketNumber = " & Me.text79

If DCount("*", "tblBookings", strWhere) > 0 Then
   code for Record found goes here
Else
   code reocrd not found code here
End If
```

So either way should suffice here.

Comment: Awesome explanation. above Solution is Working perfectly :-)